# How to get all table ids inside a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div having n number of tables, now i want to alert all table ids inside that div only using jquery.

Here is the example code :

```
<div id="myDiv">

<table id="table1"><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>

<table id="table2"><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>

<table id="table3"><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>

<table id="table4"><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>

<table id="table5"><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>

</div>
```

Assume that i already know div id which is 'myDiv'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try,

```
$('#myDiv table').each(function(){ 
   alert(this.id);  
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8gFeB/1/)**

Comment: No prob...+1 for `this.id` . We often forget to keep things simpler.

Answer (score 5):

```
var ids = $('#myDiv table').map(function(i, table){
    return table.id;
}).get();

alert(ids.join(', '));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8uAg/1/

Answer (score 2):

You should use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate. Try this:

```
$("#myDiv table").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/8gFeB/)**